# Emit Date Object in Event Emitter for Date Picker

Tags: javascript, angular, datepicker

I have a custom Date Picker Child Component, where onDateChange event, I want to emit an event to parent component.

```
@Output() selectedDateChange = new EventEmitter<Date>();
onDateChange($event) {
    this.selectedDateChange.emit($event); //$event has proper Date Value
}
```

In the parent component, in my html I have

```
<app-custom-date (selectedDateChange) = "onSomeTestMethod($event")> </app-custom-date>
```

and in TS

```
someAttrib: Date;
onSomeTestMethod($event) {
   this.someAttrib = $event; //type of $event is Object but has proper data
}
```

I am having issues in casting $event of type object to Date in Angular

Comment: when did you trigger onDataChange ?? can you share the source of app-customer-data

Comment: Could you please describe with a little more detail, what $event object is? I mean, its structure, properties.

Comment: $event is Date Object. onDateChange is triggered on (onChange) event of Date Picker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I use a input of type date I have get the value of it and it was a string then I parse the string value to date check this example

custome date

```
<input  type="date" #v (change)="onDateChange(v.value)" />
```

component

```
  @Output() selectedDateChange = new EventEmitter<Date>();

  onDateChange(value) {        
    this.selectedDateChange.emit( new Date(value));
  }
```

app.component

*template*

```
<app-custom-data (selectedDateChange)="log($event)"></app-custom-data>
```

*component*

```
  log(value){
    console.log(typeof value); // object
    console.log( value instanceof Date); // true value is a date object
    console.log(value)
  }
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7cmf7j)